# Есть ли в php указатели?

Tags: указатели, php

Возможно ли в php реализовать указатели(ссылки) на данные?

```
<?php
session_start();
function foo(&$boo){
    $_SESSION['boo']=$boo;
}
$boo=1;
foo($boo);
$boo=2;
var_dump($boo);             // int(2)
var_dump($_SESSION['boo']); // int(1)
?>
```

В данном случае в сессию пишется значение, а не указатель.

Comment: в php указателей для общего пользования нет, есть аналоги:

 <?php
   $boo = 1;
   $_SESSION['boo']='$boo';
   $boo = 2;
 
   echo 'boo = ', %boo;
   echo '$_SESSION[boo] = ', "${$_SESSION[boo]}";
 ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Были раньше.

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = &$a;
$a = 2;
echo $b; //2
?>
```

Сейчас уже deprecated вроде;
А вот по Вашему коду:

> ```
> function foo(&$boo){
>     $_SESSION['boo']=$boo;
> }
> ```
>
> В данном случае в сессию пишется
> значение, а не указатель.

WAT?

```
$_SESSION['boo']=&$boo;
```

Разве нет?
И ответ как раз будет:

> int 2
>
> int 2

Comment: На сколько помню, в php.ini есть опция, которая управляет разрешением на использование оператора `&`, так что решение может и правильное, но на чужом хостинге доставит проблем.

Comment: @stck Я же не из головы брал дампы, а предварительно прогнал код на своей машинке :)

Comment: @stck сорри не вгляделся в твой вариант. Надо попробовать.

Comment: Как это. Есть же замечательная функция ini_set().

Comment: >Как это. Есть же замечательная функция ini_set().

allow_call_time_pass_reference PHP_INI_SYSTEM|PHP_INI_PERDIR

это означает, что allow_call_time_pass_reference можно поставить только из php.ini либо из .htaccess, что регламентируется хостером. Так что нет, `ini_set` не поможет.

Кроме того:
>Начиная с PHP 5.4.0 передача переменной по ссылке стала невозможна, поэтому использование этого приема приведет к фатальной ошибке.

Comment: @mega, не имел проблем с ini_set();

>Сейчас уже deprecated вроде;

A это указал

Comment: @stck, а с `ini_set` и нет проблем, просто она позволяет ставить не все [флаги php](http://www.php.su/functions/?ini-set). Пометка `PHP_INI_USER` означает доступность флага из `ini_set`. Для `allow_call_time_pass_reference` этой возможности нет.

Comment: @mega, спасибо за расширение кругозора, я был слеп))

Answer (score -1):

Так вы и передаете значение а не указатель, что бы был указатель нужно так сделать

```
session_start();
function foo(&$boo){
    $_SESSION['boo']=&$boo;
}
$boo=1;
foo($boo);
$boo=2;
var_dump($boo);             // int(2)
var_dump($_SESSION['boo']); // int(1)
```

[Подробнее про указатели с примером использования](http://web-sprints.ru/php-ssyilki-na-peremennuyu/)